# In Israel, can one eat Chametz brought in by a Gentile this Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, gentiles, chametz-leaven

This Shabbat, in Israel, will follow after the end of Pesach. Since it is not Pesach, Israelis are allowed to eat chametz. However, since their own chametz has not been bought back, they cannot eat that.

Let's say a Gentile brings his chametz to your home. Can you eat this chametz?

Several scenarios I'm interested in:

- Can you eat this if your request him to do this during Pesach itself
- Can you eat it if you request of him to do this before Pesach began
- Can you eat it of he shows up with his chametz unasked and says, "I have too much. Why don't you take some of mine?"

IN all cases, the chametz is his own. He is not purchasing chametz during Pesach specifically for you.

Possible concern - are any of these scenarios asking him to do any melacha or still in some way considered as if you owned chametz just because you asked him this favor?